# Elasticsearch: Datatype for time(HH:mm:ss.SSS) field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

I want to index one field that contains only time in HH:mm:ss.SSS format. Which datatype I can use to store this field in elasticsearch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `date` mapping type with a [specific date format](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html) to accomodate your data:

```
{
  "my_field": {
    "type": "date",
    "format": "hour_minute_second_fraction"

  }
}
```

Comment: Could you help me on this , in     "releasedate":{
      "type": "date",
      "format": "hour_minute_second_fraction"
    }, I added this in my PUT request to add the mapping . To insert the data , I gave like   "runtime": "1_50.30_12", . Could you suggest an approach  in Kibana 7.9.2 ? Thank you.

Comment: @SameeraDeSilva please create a new question as this one is closed

Comment: thank  you , added https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64384551/kibana-v-7-9-2-exact-format-for-hour-minute-second