# Kibana v 7.9.2 exact format for hour_minute_second

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-7

I followed

and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html but I could not find the answer that required .

I created index using

```
 GET film/_mapping
```

Also as per the accepted answer in [Elasticsearch: Datatype for time(HH:mm:ss.SSS) field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46071869/elasticsearch-datatype-for-timehhmmss-sss-field/46071925?noredirect=1#comment113849612_46071925)

I created my mapping as per below .

```
PUT film/_mapping 
{
  
  "properties": {
    "filmname": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "runtime": {
      "type": "date",
      "format": "hour_minute_second_fraction"
    },
      "genre": {
      "type": "text"
    },
    "releasedate":{
      "type": "date",
      "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
    },
    "budget":{
      "type": "double"
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to add a document using below request .

```
PUT film/_doc/1/
{
  "film": "The Terminator",
  "runtime": "12_50_30_40",
  "genre": "SCIFI war Action",
  "releasedate": "1984-11-30",
  "budget" : "45.12"
}
```

But it throws the attached error , actually I want to add this field only in hour_minute_second format.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format expected by `hour_minute_second_fraction` is `HH:mm:ss.SSS`, so in your case, it would mean `12:50:30.400`

If you want to keep using `12_50_30_40`, then you need to set your own format, like this:

```
"runtime": {
  "type": "date",
  "format": "HH_mm_ss_SS"
},
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Val ,both worked . In mapping I gave like       "format":"HH:mm:ss"  and value as  "12:50:30" . Have a nice day.

Comment: By the way since you are expert on ElK Slack , could you please look at this as well , I'm new to this tool though and this is bit of an out of the box question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64256088/elasticsearch-what-are-the-formulas-to-calculate-total-shards